# When concatenating using COALESCE, number more than 9 displays as asterisk *

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, numbers, concatenation

I want to concatenate values from multiple rows into one. I am using COALESCE for this purpose. One of the columns I have is an ID column. When concatenating ID column, values up to 9 are displayed correctly but after nine, asterisk is displayed. Anyone knows why this is? See my code below using COALESCE to concatenate all rows in one:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(id int, name varchar(50))
insert into #test
values(1, 'ana'),
(2, 'bob'),
(3, 'steph'),
(4, 'bill'),
(5, 'john'),
(6, 'jose'),
(7, 'kerry'),
(8, 'frank'),
(9, 'noah'),
(10, 'melissa')

--SELECT * FROM #test 

DECLARE @NameAndID VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @NameAndID = COALESCE(@NameAndID +'; ', '') + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(1))+'. ' + name
FROM #test 

SELECT @NameAndID
```

Comment: Well, a `VarChar(1)` can only hold a single digit and `10` is clearly two digits. To avoid truncating the result it's returned as `*`

Comment: What is your desired result based on your sample data?

Comment: @dnoeth This is it!!! Can't believe I spent so much time on this and couldn't see the length of 1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting the number to `varchar(1)` - and any number that have more than a single digit will overflow the one char and therefor will be turned into an asterisks (`*`).

When casting ints, I find it best to use `varchar(11)`, since this covers the maximum amount of chars that might be needed to display an int.
The `int` minimum value is -2,147,483,648 - removing the thousands separators it's 10 digits and a minus sign:

```
-2147483648
123456789 1 (10 is missing in the chars count to make it more clear)
```

By the way, there are better ways of doing string aggregation in T-Sql.

For versions prior to 2017, use a combination of `stuff` and `for xml path`, like this:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (
        SELECT '; ' + CAST(id as varchar(11)) + '. ' + name
        FROM #test
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1 ,2, '')
```

For version 2017 or higher, use the built in `string_agg` function, like this:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(id as varchar(11)) + '. '+ name, '; ')
FROM #Test
```

for more information, check out [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672860/3094533)

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327) Be sure to read the link I've edited in and also the link to the relevant documentation in Salman's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is an indicator that the *result length (was) too short to display*. In your example you're trying to fit a two digit number into `VARCHAR(1)`. In this particular case the result is the `*` instead of throwing an error.

The behavior [is described in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#truncating-and-rounding-results).